# Unable to create directory in hadoop

Tags: hadoop2, mkdir

I have tried to create a directory by using below command

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /home/myuser/data1
```

its showing "/home/myuser/data1" no such file or directory.

But, where below command is working fine.

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp/data1
```

(Using hadoop 2.7.0)

I could not get, why its not creating inside my user directory, but allowing to create in tmp directory (/tmp/).

Comment: Check if one level up directory exists or not i.e. `hadoop fs -ls /home/myuser` One can not create 2 levels of HDFS folders structure in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Abhiieor comment, hadoop fs -mkdir not allowing to create directory more than 2 level. Below command works fine.

```
pwd # /home/

hadoop fs -mkdir myuser/data1

hadoop fs -ls myuser/  #showing data1 directory
```

Thnaks Abhiieor.

http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/using-commandline-manage-files-hdfs/

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p '/home/myuser/data1'
```

this should create entire path.

Comment: thanks sumeet, it works same as linux syntax. but I haven't tried this. :p

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to execute this command being in home directory which does not work. If you want to create any folder in your home directory you can just type mkdir your_dir_name and it will create directory for you. The second command works as this will create a directory in root folder not under your home directory.. Hope it helps

Comment: why can't i create inside home directory with hadoop command. is there any reason?

Comment: Its not with Hadoop command. Any other unix command also works the same way. You can try the mkdir command with your example in any unix machine and you will get the same results

Comment: i dont think so, we can execute mkdir /home/myuser/data1. it will work.